# XMLSerialization with no root element

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a relatively simple string in C# below. An XML response is received from a REST API call. The response from the API is being stored in a string because the built-in converter for the Spring.Rest is failing to convert to an XMLDocument object so I am trying to create a work around.

Here is the basic scenario:

```csharp
// Response from API
string emailData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>"
    + "<email-address>xyz@gmail.com</email-address>";


// Code calling the conversion of the string
Console.WriteLine(
    XmlConversion.XmlDeserializeFromString(emailData, typeof(Email)).ToString());


// Object being Deserialized into 
public class Email
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("email-address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}    


// Conversion Class
public static class XmlConversion
{
    public static string XmlSerializeToString(this object objectInstance)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectInstance.GetType());
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, objectInstance);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static T XmlDeserializeFromString<T>(string objectData)
    {
        return (T)XmlDeserializeFromString(objectData, typeof(T));
    }

    public static object XmlDeserializeFromString(string objectData, Type type)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        object result;

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(objectData))
        {
            result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the definition of the class to:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("email-address")]
public class email
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText()]
    public string emailAddress { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Great, this works. I did find an error in my Console.WriteLine statement. I fixed that as follows...  email myemail=(email) xmlConversion.XmlDeserializeFromString(emaildata, typeof(email));
            Console.WriteLine(myemail.emailAddress);